# JavaScript array passed as ref but can't assign ref to a new array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, pass-by-reference

If I pass an array into a function and make changes to the array within the function, the array that exists outside the function reflects those effects.  E.g.:

```
var myArr = [1, 2, 3];
function popAll(arr) {
    while(arr.length) {
        arr.pop();
    }
}
popAll(myArr);
console.log(myArr.length); // prints "0"
```

However, if I try to reassign the array reference to point to another array in the function, it does not stick:

```
var myArr = [1, 2, 3];
function reassign(arr) {
    while(arr.length) {
        arr.pop();
    }
    var newArr = [1,2,3,4,5];
    arr = newArr;
}
reassign(myArr);
console.log(myArr.length); // still prints "0"!!
```

What am I missing?  I want `reassign(...)` to assign the reference to the new array.

**Edit:**

I do not want to return the new array.  I want to reassign the incoming reference.  Also, I want to learn why JS has this behavior that appears to be inconsistent (or I don't know enough about to understand how it is consistent).

Comment: change line 7 to `return newArr;` and change line 9 to `myArr = reassign(myArr);`

Comment: @PatrickRoberts thanks for this answer, if you post it as a full answer I'll happily accept it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All function calls in JavaScript are pass-by-value.

This may seem counter-intuitive, but it makes more sense if you consider that the `arr` parameter is itself a reference, so it's a reference, passed by value. Assigning `newArr` to `arr` will not modify the old reference, it will simply change what `arr` references within the scope of the function.

As [Zeb Rawnsley pointed out in comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53177025/javascript-array-passed-as-ref-but-cant-assign-ref-to-a-new-array/53177267#comment93244162_53177025), you must return the new reference from the function and assign the outer variable to the return value:

```js
var myArr = [1, 2, 3];

function reassign(arr) {
    while(arr.length) {
        arr.pop();
    }
    var newArr = [1,2,3,4,5];
    return newArr;
}

myArr = reassign(myArr);

console.log(myArr.length);
```

Just pointing out that you don't need to pass in the old reference or empty it, it will automatically be garbage-collected once there are zero references left to the memory that `myArr` initially allocated:

```js
var myArr = [1, 2, 3];

function reassign() {
    return [1,2,3,4,5];
}

myArr = reassign();

console.log(myArr.length);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't assign the value of an array to another array, but you can add the elements from one array to another.

This should do the trick for you:

```
var myArr = [1, 2, 3];
function reassign(arr) {
    while(arr.length) {
        arr.pop();
    }
    var newArr = [1,2,3,4,5];
    for(var num in newArr){
        arr.push(num);
    }
}
reassign(myArr);
console.log(myArr.length); //prints 5
```